# Probability of ordered sequence of events?

Tags: probability

If I roll a dice 3 times, the chance of me getting $3$, $5$ and $6$, in any order, is $\frac{1}{6^3}$. But what is the probability that I get $3$, $5$ and $6$ in *exactly* that order and why? I mean, the probability must be smaller for a specific permutation of $\{3,5,6\}$ and any permutation.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. The probability of **correctly guessing three dice throws in a row** is $\frac{1}{6^3}$ (assuming you guess only one number and that the die is fair). In order to calculate the probability for getting 3, 5, and 5 in any order, you can consider the number of orderings of these three numbers ($3!$). Then divide that number by the total number ouf outcomes ($6^3$)

Answer (score 2):

The probability of getting 3, 5, and 6 in *exactly* that order is in fact $\frac{1}{6^3}$.

Getting them in any order is: $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$ because first roll, you have one-half chance of getting 3, 5, or 6. The second roll, you have one-third (or two out of 6) chance of getting one of the remaining two numbers. On the third roll, you have one-sixth chance of getting the final number.

Comment: The connection between $\frac{1}{36}$ and $\frac{1}{6^3}$ can be made: since there are $3!$ ways to arrange the numbers in any order, it is $3!$ more likely to get any permutation of the numbers.

Comment: @TobyMak Don't you mean the other way around then? "It is $3!$ more likely to get any permutation of the numbers" - but he wgb states that it is 3! times more likely to get one exact permutation than any permutation (1/36 for "Getting them in any order" and 1/6^3 for one exact order)

Comment: I should better say: 'a permutation of the numbers in any order': you are right.